# How do I modify a in-progress call by sending a digit with Twilio-Python?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have an app that makes a outbound call to user A.

User A answers and either says "foo" or "bar"

If User A says **"foo"** -> `c.calls(callSid).update(status="complete")`

If User A says **"bar"** -> `twilio.update('press the number 2')`

How can I implement this?

I'm using the Python helper library and have tried this.

`call = c.calls(callSid).update(twiml="<Play digits='2'/>")`

But the app errors out.

Comment: Can you share the error you get? It might help figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your outbound call use TwiML to ask the user to say "foo" or "bar" and then supply a webhook which can be called to process the response, i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech" timeout="5" action="<your webhook>">
        <Say>Please say foo or bar.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Twilio will do a `POST` to the specified webhook in `action` and the user answer will be stored in `SpeechResult` along with a confidence score in `Confidence`. You can then continue with your business logic as you outlined.

For more information on `Gather` have a look at the [TwiML documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather).